# Parallel programming using MPI in serial code

Tags: parallel-processing

I want to parallelize a part of serial code and I have done this

```
void Cup::tellMoleculesToMove()
{
   fullPosition dfp; 
   int rank,task,i;  

    for(list<Molecule*>::iterator mlc = Active_Molecules.begin(); mlc != Active_Molecules.end(); ++mlc) 
    {
        std::vector<Gestalt>::iterator it;
        std::vector<Gestalt> *gstV = (*mlc)->getGestalten();

        for(it =gstV->begin()+rank*task; it!=gstV->begin()+rank*task+task;it++) 
        {
            // calculate displacement from all the force contributions and perform step
            (it)->makeBrownianStep();

            MPI_Bcast(&dfp.pos[0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Bcast(&dfp.pos[1],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Bcast(&dfp.pos[2],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            MPI_Bcast(&dfp.rot.phi,1,MPI_DOUBLE,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Bcast(&dfp.rot.n[0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Bcast(&dfp.rot.n[1],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Bcast(&dfp.rot.n[2],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is after parallelizing the wall time increases as the number of processor increases. How can we solve this?

Comment: [`MPI_Type_create_struct`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man3/MPI_Type_create_struct.3.php) could be used to create a MPI datatype dedicated to `dfp`. That way, `MPI_Bcast()` can be called only once per loop. See [there](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/mpi_type_create_struct.html) for instance.

Comment: Is there any other way of parallelizing the problem to reduce the parallel time

Comment: My guess is that most of molecular dynamic programs only handle potentials featuring a finite range `R`. That way, a particle is only influenced by the nearby particles. Let's split the domain using a grid, so that each process must compute the forces for the particles in the cell. The process only have to keep trace of the particles in a box larger than the cell. Once the positions of all particles are updated, the relevant new positions are send by a process to its neigbours. That way, communications are limited and there is only a couple of big messages at the end of each time step.

Comment: Lastly, in `MPI_Bcast()`, all process in the communicator must use the same value for argument `root`. Hence, if `rank` is the rank of the process, `MPI_Bcast(&dfp.pos[0],1,MPI_DOUBLE,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD);` will likely result in a deadlock. All processes will try to send messages to other processes and these messages will never be received. The program runs endlessly, until then next power outage (or kill signal).

Comment: can you help me in splitting the domain using grid

Comment: As I am new to MPI I dont know the grid spiltting concept.Can you help me with it